# Are these operators adjoint?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ be the Schwartz space. Then define $A:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ and $B:\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ given by $$Af(x) = f'(x)-2\pi xf(x)$$ $$Bf(x) = -f'(x)-2\pi xf(x).$$ Then is it true that the $\langle Af,g\rangle = \langle f,Bg\rangle$ where the inner product is the one in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I am just confused on how one could interchange the derivative on $f$ to be on $g$. Perhaps we have to use that the Fourier transform preserves inner-product to do this. But even when calculating that I cannot get to the end. Any help is welcomed!

Comment: Integration by parts.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts: Thank you for the quick comment. Could you perhaps explain a bit more?

Comment: $$\langle Af, g \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g (f' - 2 \pi x f) dx = gf \bigg\lvert_{\mathbb{R}} + \int_{\mathbb{R}} f (- g' - 2 \pi x g) dx = 0 + \langle f, Bg \rangle$$

Comment: @mattos: Agh, of course. Thank you for helping me understand!

Comment: No worries. Might I suggest that you post a detailed answer to your question below and then accept it yourself so that the question is considered complete.

Comment: @mattos: Thank you for the suggestion. Will do it soon!